# Typewriter effect is displaying the text before the animation begins

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a multi-line typewriter effect on my site. I have the code below and it does work except it shows the text before the animation occurs. So while the first line is typing, the second shows below it. After the first line types out, then the second line disappears and types out. I feel like I must be missing something small. I am pretty new to coding.

```css
/*copy and paste this into your CSS editor*/

.typewriter p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.typewriter p:nth-child(1) {
  /*If you are having problems with text clipping change the width from 16em to a higher value*/
  width: 16em;
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.typewriter p:nth-child(2) {
  /*If you are having problems with text clipping change the width from 13.5em to a higher value*/
  width: 16em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <p> Words have power.</p>
  <p> We leverage that power for good.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check the code again ? Because the second line is already hidden while the first line is typed.

Comment: I can’t understand why the prefixed and non prefixed versions of delay settings for child 1 are different. What browser and version number are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not see exactly what is described in the question which says the second line shows, I see the first line showing for one second before the animation begins but the second line stays hidden until its turn for animating.

The main problem seems to be that the first line has a delay of one second and during that second its opacity is at the default setting, which is 1, so we see it briefly.

There are also some inconsistencies between the -webkit- prefixed version and the non prefixed version which this snippet alters so that the timings of both are the same.

```css
/*copy and paste this into your CSS editor*/

.typewriter p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.typewriter p:nth-child(1) {
  /*If you are having problems with text clipping change the width from 16em to a higher value*/
  width: 16em;
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.typewriter p:nth-child(2) {
  /*If you are having problems with text clipping change the width from 13.5em to a higher value*/
  width: 16em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <p> Words have power.</p>
  <p> We leverage that power for good.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey all. Thanks for the help. I got this code from someone on Codepen. I tried a bunch of different ones and this was the closest to what I want to do. I'm using Squarespace, which likely complicates things. To get an idea of how it's behaving, check out: https://www.hdi.media/home-2. Obviously what I'm looking for is for line one to type out, then line 2 to follow.

Comment: When you run my snippet what do you see?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve just noticed that the opacity of the second line goes back to 0 which you’d have seen on Safari. Now should be OK. Please tell me what you see and what browser you are using.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I tested it in Firefox as well. Your code works great when I run it here in the editor. But when I copy and paste it still shows the text before it types out. https://www.hdi.media/home-2

Comment: Can you therfore edit the copied code to remove the animations and then go into your browser's devtools inspect facility  and see exactly what CSS is being applied to those texts. There must be something else overriding things because when I copy and paste the code it works perfectly well.

Comment: That's a really good idea. I'll give that a shot. It's probably some Squarespace weirdness, honestly. Thanks for all the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: In case your curious...I was able to figure it out based on your suggestion to ditch the animation and look at the code. Squarespace had a fade in setting that was a site wide style. Turned that off and bingo! Thanks again for taking the time to help me get it fixed.